# Built-in text editor in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a built-in text editor in the terminal on Lion?

(Like, for example, `nano` on Linux.)

Comment: umm... like `vim`, `emacs`?

Comment: @Jay Did you even try running `nano` in the Terminal?

Comment: @CajunLuke No, for some reason I thought it wasn't there. Oh well.

Comment: I disagree with the heavy down vote penalty you've incurred. This is an easy question to answer if you have a Mac in front of you. But if you don't have a Mac at hand or don't own one yet and are wondering what the command line experience is like this is potentially useful information. Just because something seems obvious or is well known to you doesn't mean that's the case for everyone else.

Comment: When Apple stopped shipping their current OS with GNU Emacs, they replaced it with mg.

Comment: @WHO'sNoToOldRx4CovidIsMurder Out of curiosity, do you know which mg Apple is shipping?  It calls itself 'mg 2a'... the common ports of that are the ibara, the bootes, and the troglobit.  It's not the ibara, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[vim](http://www.vim.org/), [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/) and [pico](http://www.washington.edu/pine/) are all available by default with OS X 10.7.4:

```
/Users/ian
> which nano
/usr/bin/nano

/Users/ian
> which vim
/usr/bin/vim

/Users/ian
> which emacs
/usr/bin/emacs

> which pico
/usr/bin/pico
```

Comment: They've been on every Mac I've ever used since the 10.2 days, and I'd be shocked if OS X had *ever* not included them.

Comment: And for hard core users there is even `/bin/ed` :-)

Comment: @CajunLuke: actually, nano was added in 10.4 (although pico, the editor it's based on, was in at least 10.3).  I can't say for certain about emacs, but I'm pretty sure vi was there in [Rhapsody Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Server_1.0).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Nano was definitely around in 10.2 and 10.3. I remember using it (and I've an old 10.3 Mac I can check on if needed).

Comment: @CajunLuke: I just checked under 10.3.9 computer (server version, but that shouldn't matter) and it has pico but not nano.  I don't have a 10.2 machine handy anymore...

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'll bet nano is symlinked to hard-linked to pico. I learned to use the command-line when I was using 10.2, and the editor I used was nano.

Comment: Emacs was removed in Catalina. It can be installed with Homebrew. I guess vi won the war at Apple. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since `ed` has not been mentioned yet, even thought I'd choose to use `nano` over it and the others mentioned, let me offer it as an addition to the cumulative list.

The manual page for [`ed`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ed.1.html) states:

> The **ed** utility is a line-oriented text editor.  It is used to create, display, modify and otherwise manipulate text files.

Comment: `The ed utility does not recognize multibyte characters.`, so it's use may be rather small nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is about "built-in" editors *"like"* nano, this question needs an updated answer:

The command `pico` is just a *symlink* to nano, `vi` is actually vim as is `ex` and not counting `awk` or `psed`, `cat`, `xargs`, constructions and the like, thats about it, since ed is indeed present but very unlike nano (depending on the definition of "editor").

Three CLI text editors (*like nano*) are present in the default of Sierra:

- [nano](https://www.nano-editor.org) (installed:  2.0.6, current:  2.8.7. "Of course, you should always check the nano homepage to see what the latest and greatest version is.")

  > GNU nano is designed to be a free replacement for the Pico text editor, part of the Pine email suite from The University of Washington. It aims to "emulate Pico as closely as possible and then include extra functionality".
- [vim](http://www.vim.org) (installed: Vi IMproved 7.4, current: "Vim 8.0 is the latest stable version")

  > Vim is a highly configurable text editor built to make creating and changing any kind of text very efficient. It is included as "vi" with most UNIX systems and with Apple OS X.
- [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (installed: GNU Emacs 22.1.1, current: "Emacs 25.3 − latest release
  Released September 11, 2017 Emacs 25.3 fixes a significant security hole.")

  > An extensible, customizable, free/libre text editor — and more.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ones listed above there is also xedit. It's opened from the terminal by just typing xedit. Opens an editor window where you can edit a file with keyboard and mouse.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `xedit` requires XQuartz/X11 to be installed (and that launching X11 just to edit a file might be kind of overkill).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nano and vim for example are installed with Mac OS X.