# Simple Console Editor for OS X Terminal

Tags: terminal, text-editor, console

I am looking for a simple console text editor for OS X to run in a terminal. I have used “Joe” for many years, and it’s very good, but I am looking for one that is simpler.

In particular I would prefer one that uses copy & paste like modern text editors, and allows you to select text with the shift-arrow keys.

Windows has the built-in editor called “Edit”. Something like that would be nice.

Comment: What do you mean by "console editor"? If you mean an editor that runs in a terminal window, you can always use Emacs. The one bundled with OS X is old but still usable, you can download a newer version from "emacsforosx.com". (However, Emcas might not land in the "simple" section, though.)

Comment: @Lindydancer I’ve edit the question accordingly. It’s to run in a termminal.

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53444/built-in-text-editor-in-terminal , http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97595/simple-text-editor-that-supports-highlighting-and-font-colours and a lot more via [search](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=editor+osx).

Comment: The requirement to run in Terminal pretty much excludes any modern conventions like selecting with the shift-arrow keys or interacting with the system clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of editors running in Terminal already installed by default. Some of them come with quite a learning curve though...

- `nano` rather easy to use, onscreen help, limited functionality
- `emacs` takes some time to get used to, start with the tutorial (type <kbd>Ctrl-h t</kbd>)
- `vi`/`vim` takes some time to get used to as well, especially because it's a modal editor, start with the help document (type <kbd>:help</kbd>)

And of course there is also `Textedit.app`. Doesn't run in Terminal but is quite a versatile editor to get started.